# Understanding the logic behind my "proof" of a false statement

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, fake-proofs

I was working through these questions:

```
(c) Prove that f(C1 ∩ C2) ⊆ f(C1) ∩ f(C2).
(d) Give a counterexample to the opposite inclusion in (c).
```

The opposite of c. (that is, the RHS is not a subset of the LHS)  is false. This is their answer which makes sense to me:

```
(d) Let f : R → R be given by f(x) = x^2.
Let C1 = {−2}, and let C2 = {2}. Then f(C1 ∩ C2) = f(∅) = ∅, but f(C1) ∩ f(C2) = {4} ̸⊆ ∅.
```

However, if it is false, I was trying to prove that utilizing methods I have learned (utilizing the pre-image of a function).

[image]

I proved c. using essentially the same logic but reversed. In my proof of the false statement, this logic seems true to me but I know it should be a false statement... any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your counterexample d) illustrates exactly what is wrong with your argument. 
From $x\in f(C_1)$ you cannot conlcude that $f^{-1}(x) \subseteq C_1$, the preimage can be much bigger!, e.g. in the counterexample $4\in f(\{2\})$, but $f^{-1}(4)=\{-2,2\}\not \subseteq {2}$.

Comment: Some times you have a statement you know is false because you have an actual counterexample, and you have a proof that the statement is true, which means there must be a flaw somewhere. Then to find the flaw it is usually a very good idea to go through the steps of the proof thoroughly with the concrete counterexample in mind every step of the way. Figure out at what point you say something that doesn't apply to your counterexample, and you have found the flaw in your proof.